# Azure Free Trial Account Disabled and Account Center not Accesible

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to using azure and have been trying to connect my mobile azure app to my xamarin forms app, however I have ran into some problems and have come to find out that my account is disabled. I have searched around for awhile and found out that I need to go to the Azure account center to reactivate my account, however when I try to go to the account center a page pops up saying "We are sorry, but we could not complete that operation." and so I can't change any account settings. I really need help as this is keeping me from developing my app further.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Comment: What @SushiHangover said - SO cannot help you with account/billing problems

Answer (score 1):

Contact billing support team for better assistance (which is a free service provided by MS) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/